# Asynchronous FileReader Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm new in Angular. I use FileReader to get information about blob file. How I know, it's asynchronous. All actions stoped on

> fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(res);

and don't go any further. How I can solve this problem?

My service's methods:

```
download(fileId: string): Observable<Blob> {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders();
  let header: string;
  let contentType: string;
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
  return this._http.get( this._api.powerLoadApi.getFileLink(this.WellId, fileId), {
    headers: headers,
    responseType: 'blob',
  })
  .map(res => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(res);
    fileReader.onloadend = function(event){
    let signatureArray = (new Uint8Array(this.result).subarray(0,4));        
    for (let i = 0; i < signatureArray.length; i++){
      header += signatureArray[i].toString(16);
    };
  }

  console.log(contentType);
  contentType = this.getContentType(header);
  return new Blob([res], {type: contentType});
  });    
}

getContentType(signature: string): string {
  switch(signature){
    case "25504446":
      return "application/pdf";
    case "ffd8ffe0":
    case "ffd8ffe1":
    case "ffd8ffe2":
    case "ffd8ffe3":
    case "ffd8ffe8":
      return "image/jpg";
 }  
}
```

My component method:

```
getFile(file: WellFile) {
    this._fileService.download(file.id)
        .subscribe(res => {
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
    window.open(url);    
  });
  }
```

So what I get in browser:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZZh7.jpg)

Comment: may you please mention full error you get.

Comment: [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) is asynchronous, per the docs.

Comment: @fatemefazli I don' get any error. Content type doesn not returned from getContentType(header), cuz FileReader does asynchronous call. So in browser blob opened without Content Type.

Comment: @R.Richards yea, I know, but what I have to do to solve this problem? I tried use async/await, but app not worked.

Comment: Try changing the `onloadend` from a function, to an arrow function. Like this: `fileReader.onloadend = (event : any) => {...`. That is really what you should be doing anyway so you have access to `this` inside the callback. I have no idea if that will fix the performance issue.

Comment: @R.Richards Tried, but problem doesn't solved. :(

Comment: Maybe, doing this in the map is the wrong approach. Maybe you should do this work where you subscribe to the http call. I'm just guess now. Good luck to you!